# 'actions' isn't defined in Flutter Local Notifications with Action Buttons

Tags: android, flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I am trying to implement flutter local notification with action buttons, but I don't know what is wrong, I don't see any `actions` option in the `AndroidNotificationDetails` in my project but the weird thing is, if I see the GitHub Repository of official flutter local notifications package then there is `actions` option which also works, I have tested it.
So why does it show `The named parameter 'actions' isn't defined.` in my project but works in theirs? Apart from a notification with actions, everything works fine!

Dependency - [flutter_local_notifications:](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) [^9.2.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/versions/9.2.0)

MyCode:

[image]

Code from sample project:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide the link for the repo?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications)!

Comment: and the file file path? there are too many files.

Comment: This [one](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications)

Comment: Check my answer please.

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the reason that you are not able to use this because `actions` feature is in `dev mode` and `flutter_local_notifications` has not published any `stable` version for it if you want to use this `feature` then you need to use latest under `development` dependency like below :

```
flutter_local_notifications: ^10.0.0-dev.3
```